# How to print UTF-8 characters on console using C

Tags: c, windows, encoding, utf-8, eclipse-cdt

I have a C application where I receive a UTF-8 string aover a socket as a char*. Now I want to print it on the console using Eclipse CDT. How can I do this? What I get is usually something like "GÃ¼nther" what should be "Günther"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which **OS**???

Comment: Have you checked the locales and such? If that doesn't work, check wide chars and wide strings. If that doesn't work, try converting the string yourself. I honestly don't remember how to do this, but I think the answer is in one of those things.

Comment: This is your console's problem. It's not interpreting your output as UTF-8.

Comment: Your program is outputting correct `UTF-8` to the console, but your console is set to display the `iso-8859-1` charset. How you change the console to use `UTF-8` depends on what program you're using to show the console, not your C application.

Comment: I think the absence of pointing out OS means Windows.

Comment: I am on Windows / eclipse cdt

Comment: `chcp 65001` will switch console to Unicode.

Comment: `chcp 65001` will switch the console to `UTF-8`, which is one of several possible encodings of Unicode. Unicode isn't an encoding (or "code page" in MS parlance) in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer given above was by Joachim Isaksson. Thank you, this ideed seems to be the problem. I solved it in Eclipse by setting the "Encoding" settings for the run configuration to UTF-8.

[image]
[image]